# C# Bitwise Operators

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

Could someone please explain what the following code does.

```
private int ReadInt32(byte[] _il, ref int position)
{
    return (((il[position++] | (il[position++] << 8)) | (il[position++] << 0x10)) | (il[position++] << 0x18));
}
```

I'm not sure I understand how the bitwise operators in this method work, could some please break it down for me?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ?

Comment: I'd change it to `return (((il[position] | (il[position+1] << 8)) | (il[position+2] << 0x10))` (not answering the question, someone has already done that, it's just that the `position++` stuff is just hard to read and unnecessary)

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I agree that it makes far more sense, but it seems that it is used in a loop over a buffer from an external function, as the `position` argument is `ref int` so the callee likely depends on index being updated. still, I would do it like you and just add `pos += 4` at the end

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Ah yes, quite right. Probably `position += sizeof(int)` would be even more expressive.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, right, I completely forgot that C# also has `sizeof` operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The integer is given as a byte array.
Then each byte is shifted left 0/8/16/24 places and these values are summed to get the integer value.

This is an `Int32` in hexadecimal format:

```
0x10203040
```

It is represented as following byte array (little endian architecture, so bytes are in reverse order):

```
[0x40, 0x30, 0x20, 0x10]
```

In order to build the integer back from the array, each element is shifted i.e. following logic is performed:

```
a = 0x40        = 0x00000040
b = 0x30 << 8   = 0x00003000
c = 0x20 << 16  = 0x00200000
d = 0x10 << 24  = 0x10000000
```

then these values are OR'ed together:

```
int result = a | b | c | d;

this gives:

0x00000040 |
0x00003000 | 
0x00200000 |
0x10000000 |
------------------
0x10203040
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes much more sense now! :)

Answer (score 3):

Think of it like this:

```
var i1 = il[position];
var i2 = il[position + 1] << 8;  (<< 8 is equivalent to * 256)
var i3 = il[position + 2] << 16; 
var i4 = il[position + 3] << 24;

position = position + 4;

return i1 | i2 | i3 | i4;
```